# Why the value of "someVariable" variable didn't change in the below code

Tags: swift, closures

I was just trying some code on the playgrounds and i come across this situation. I couldn't comprehend why the value of `someVariable` was not updated in the below code. Can someone explain me what is this behaviour?

```
var someVariable = "something"
let closure = { [someVariable] in
    print("This is \(someVariable)")
}
someVariable = "otherVariable"
closure()
```

BTW the output of the code is `This is something`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`closure`'s capture the object to be used inside the closure upon declaration. When an object of **Value**(`struct`) type or **Reference**(`class`) type is captured by a closure, it will behave differently.

For example, in your case, `someVariable`(i.e, `String`) is a `Value` type so once it is captured by the closure, it will keep a copy of the actual value of this variable. When you assign a new value to `someVariable`, the copy inside the closure will not change.

But if you capture a `Reference` type object inside a `closure` then it will `retain` a `reference` to that `object` and any change on that object will reflect inside the closure as well. See the below example,

```
class Bhai {
    public var kam: String = ""
}

let b = Bhai()
b.kam = "something"
let closure = { [b] in
    print("This is \(b.kam)")
}
b.kam = "otherVariable"
closure()
// prints This is otherVariable
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `closure` did capture reference variable `someVariable` when it init. All changed after init will not affect.

Comment: But its a `var`, we can reassign the value of the variable

Comment: @Hisenberg When you use capture list feature of closure, It will capture current variable you input.( You can understand it like copy value of your variable). Then when you update `someVariable` it will not affect the variable you did capture in closure.

Comment: @Hisenberg `[someVariable]` is capture lists of your closure. It will copy your `someVariable` variable and put in closure. Do you understand that? If you don't understand, please tell me.

Comment: Read more https://blog.bobthedeveloper.io/swift-capture-list-in-closures-e28282c71b95

Answer (score 0):

Because you pass it at the initial point and `String`s passed by their value, **not** their reference. So as soon as compiler passed through it, it gets copied with the current value(logically). [More information about this behavior here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwich_-S85_kAhWQLlAKHX2FDFwQFjACegQICxAG&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialsteacher.com%2Fcsharp%2Fcsharp-value-type-and-reference-type&usg=AOvVaw0Q7usZbgUS9r9tKlotz9vW).

At last, Change it to this and you will good to go:

```
var someVariable = "something"
let closure: (String)->() = { someVariable in
    print("This is \(someVariable)")
}
someVariable = "otherVariable"

closure(someVariable)
```

Comment: I'm not looking for code to make it work. I want to understand the why the output is "something"

Comment: > Because you pass it at the initial point and `String`s passed by their value.

Comment: I add more detail to the answer.